# How to find the index of an item skipping some values while wrapping to head

Tags: scala

I have a list of Boolean

```
val stacks = List(True, True, False, True, False)
```

I need a function that takes an index, and returns the next index that is not false, going back to 0 after reaching length.

```
def nextInvolvedAfter(after: Int): Int = ???
```

For example:

```
nextInvolvedAfter(0) // 1
nextInvolvedAfter(1) // 3
nextInvolvedAfter(2) // 3
nextInvolvedAfter(3) // 0
```

I was thinking iterating over a list like this:

```
stacks.drop(after + 1) ++ stacks indexWhere(_)
```

Comment: If you haven't noticed, we really don't like index based traversal in Scala. It comes from a highly declarative mindset and goes against what imperative approach stands for. Especially given you want to pick up from the beginning of the list  and continue once you reach the end, your best and probably only bet is to write a recursive function that will accumulate the index and keep a copy of the original list

Comment: @sinanspd I believe you mixed _declarative_ with _imperative_ on your first paragraph.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes haha! thanks for mentioning. Can't edit anymore ..

Comment: I am building a poker dealer, where player stacks are a vector, and I keep an index to tell who to act, do you have a better approach to solve this problem? @sinanspd

Comment: @eguneys I do not know too much about poker, but you mention vector and here you show list. Both are very different data structures, if you need access by index then use vectors and the solution that is using built-in methods, instead of the recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, this kind of problems are perfect to be solved using a **tail-recursive** algorithm.

```
def nextInvolvedAfter(data: List[Boolean])(after: Int): Int = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[Boolean], currentIdx: Int): Int =
    remaining match {
      case true :: _ if (currentIdx > after) => currentIdx
      case _ :: xs => loop(remaining = xs, currentIdx + 1)
      case Nil => nextInvolvedAfter(data)(after = -1) // Start again from the begining.
    }

  loop(remaining = data, currentIdx = 0)
}
```

However, if you want a solution using built-in methods, check this:

```
def nextInvolvedAfter(data: List[Boolean])(after: Int): Int =
  data.iterator.zipWithIndex.collectFirst {
    case (true, idx) if (idx > after) => idx
  }.getOrElse(nextInvolvedAfter(data)(after = -1)) // Start again from the begining.
```

Both can be tested like this:

```
val test = nextInvolvedAfter(List(true, true, false, true, false)) _
// test: Int => Int = $$Lambda$938/1778422985@51a6cc2a

test(0)
// res: Int = 1

test(1)
// res: Int = 3

test(2)
// res: Int = 3

test(3)
// res: Int = 0

test(4)
// res: Int = 0
```

However, take into account that if all values are `false` this will end in a **StackOverflow** exception, so use it with care.
Or you may add custom logic to abort after a second iteration from the beginning.

Comment: beat me to it :) i was just commenting. Note that OP wants the loop back to the front so your last 2 test cases should return 0. Just keep a ref to the original list and continue iteration on that

Comment: circular check i need, also could you look at my answer and see if it has flaws

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working:

```
(stacks.zipWithIndex.drop(after + 1) ++ stacks.zipWithIndex).find(_._1).get._2
```

Comment: Yeah seems like a good solution, you may want to play a bit with **Iterators** to make this more performant, also you shouldn't call `get` unless you are totally sure this will never fail, and finally you can always change a `find + map` with a `collectFirst`.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can simply iterate over indices. `getOrElse` can be used to do the circular check:

```
def nextInvolvedAfter(as : List[Boolean], after : Int) : Int =
  as.indices.find(i => i > after && as(i))
    .getOrElse(
    as.indices.find(i => as(i)).getOrElse(-1)
  )
```

This can be improved a little bit by trying to iterate only over the relevant portion of the list, you can directly use `scala.collection.immutable.Range` instead of `indices`.

```
def nextInvolvedAfter(as : Vector[Boolean], after : Int) : Int =
   after + 1 until as.size find as getOrElse
     0 to after find as getOrElse -1
```

Also note that iterating over a list using index is inefficient as mentioned in the comments.

Another thing to note that in all the solutions in this question (including the accepted solution) if the given index is greater than the list size, the function will just return the first **true** value encountered in the list. A trivial conditional check to make sure index is within range can remedy this.

Comment: Accessing a list by index is very inefficient, however it seems OP is really using vectors. If that is the case this seems like a great solution.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I agree. I was going to add this as a note.